laravel Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script error but there is no whitespaces
there is no space before the namespace

i turned off laravel debug and its gives error 500
UserController is used for auth
i cant load page
everytime i'm trying to change smth iv get the error
Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script error but there is no whitespaces

i was tying even try delete and make file again

The error message "Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script" typically occurs when the PHP file containing namespace declarations is not structured correctly. Here are a few common causes and solutions for this error: 1. Whitespace Before Namespace Declaration 2.PHP Opening Tag 3.Declare Calls 4. Include/Require Statements 5. UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM)
Check Other Files
